# ¿Cómo puedo llamar una función de python desde javascript en un proyecto de django?

Tags: javascript, python, django

Estoy haciendo un proyecto que requiere hacer calculadoras complejas en python, necesito pasar datos que ingresa el usuario en la pagina web, a los parámetros de un función de python, y que esta me retorne el resultado a la pagina web, para que el usuario pueda ver la respuesta. Aquí un ejemplo de la situación:

Esta es la estructura de mi proyecto:

[image: La estructura de mi proyecto]

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    {% load staticfiles %}
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <title>calculado 1</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'c1/style.css' %}">
    <script src="{% static "c1/jquery-3.1.0.min.js" %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static "c1/ux.js" %}"></script>

</head>
<body>

    <div class="formulario">
        <h1> Calculadora Prueba(suma)</h1>
        a:<input type="text" id="inputA" value="10"><br>
        b:<input type="text" id="inputB" value="5"><br>
        <input type="submit" id=btn1 value="Calcular"><br>
        respuesta:<input type="text" id="outputR" value=""><br>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

ux.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var a;
    var b;
    var outputR;

    $('#btn1').click(function() {
      console.log("click");
      a=$('#inputA').val();
      b=$('#inputB').val();
      $('#outputR').val( sumar0() );// sumar0 es la funcion de python
    });

});
```

prueba0.py:

```
def sumar0(a,b):
    return str(a+b)
```

vista del usuario:
[image: vista del usuario]

Comment: Una pregunta, para que quieres javascript en el asunto si la suma la haces en la vista de Python. Otra cosa sería si calcularas la suma y mandaras los sumandos y el resultado a Django, pero no es el caso. ¿Podrías aclararlo?

Comment: Pues, para hacer ese tipo de operaciones, incluso algo mas complejas que eso, no te recomendaría que las resolvieses con python, si no con el mismo javascript. Sin embargo si son operaciones que requieren de mucho procesamiento, deberias aprender AJAX, te ayudará a pasar los datos desde javascript a python

Comment: @toledano hola!, uso javascript para obtener los valores de las cajas de texto, para luego en teoría ejecutar la función de python llamada en este caso "suma0", es decir hacer que sume, y devolverme esa respuesta a la caja de texto identificada con el id "outputR". Lo quise hacer así porque creí que seria mas fácil comunicar javascript con python, ahora bien si crees que hay alguna manera mejor utilizando un puente, estoy abierto a sugerencias =) gracias.

Comment: @GermanAlzate hola!, es que debo necesariamente usar python para las funciones de la calculadora, son cosas como método de newton, método de bisección, etc.., el requerimiento de mi cliente es que debe ser hechas solo en python. por eso solo utilizo el javascript para obtener datos =) gracias

Comment: ¿Sabes hacer vistas de Django? No es necesario que tengas un modelo, ni un formulario genérico, pero si una ruta y una vista para hacer tu suma.

Comment: básicamente el problema es que no puedo llamar a la función llamada sumar0 de python desde javascript así de facil como lo puse en el ejemplo, pues así no funciona, tal vez la clave este usando AJAX pero no se como podría hacerlo la verdad @GermanAlzate

Comment: @toledano  ¿te refieres al view.py? se que pueden hacerse funciones allí, pero y luego como las llamaría en javascript o en html, pues para que se ejecute al oprimir el botón calcular, teniendo en cuenta que le tengo que pasar los parámetros de las cajas de texto primero.

Comment: Tal vez te convenga mas revisar el tutorial de Django. Básicamente funciona como funciona toda la WWW. Haces una solicitud en la página, la mandas al servidor, la procesas, mandas la respuesta y la muestras en la página.

Comment: Por aclarar: "llamar a una funcion python desde javascript" es imposible. Lo unico que puedes hacer es que JS pregunte y python le responda.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Utiliza una petición AJAX para enviarles los parámetros requeridos y obtener el resultado de la misma, crea una vista que maneje esa petición y reciba los parámetros de entrada de la función.

Seria mas o menos algo así:

views.py

```
def vista_sumar(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        a = request.POST['a']
        b = request.POST['b']
        c = sumar(a,b)
        return JsonResponse({ resultado: c })
    else:
        return HttpResponse("Peticion no valida")
```

En algun lado necesariamente en la vista

```
def sumar(a, b):
    return a + b
```

Javascript + JQuery

```
$('#btn1').click(function() {
    console.log("click");
    a=$('#inputA').val();
    b=$('#inputB').val();
    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'ruta de tu vista definida en django'
        data: {
            'a': a,
            'b': b, 
        },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(response) {
            $('#outputR').val(response.resultado);
        }
    }); 
});
```