# Como llamar una función del services.py desde javascript

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, django

Estoy trabajando con Django y necesito llamar desde javascript a una función que tengo en el archivo services.py
El objetivo es que al presionar en un botón del template se llame a la función para que el servidor consuma un servicio web

```
Archivo services.py
def habilitarCajon(ip, ncajon):
    response = requests.get('http://{}/api/cajetines/enable_by_ncajetin/{}'.format(ip, ncajon))
```

Mi estructura de carpetas es: Proyecto/Apps/nombre_app/services.py

¿Cómo puedo llamar a esta función desde el template con javascript?

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Cómo puedo llamar una función de python desde javascript en un proyecto de django?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/58350/c%c3%b3mo-puedo-llamar-una-funci%c3%b3n-de-python-desde-javascript-en-un-proyecto-de-djan)

Comment: No creo que esta pregunta se ajuste a la mia, pues yo solo necesito llamar a la función al hacer click para consumir un servicio web, no tengo nada implementado en mi archivo view.py

Comment: Esa es la única manera de hacerlo, el propósito como tal es llamar la función...

Comment: Entonces para mi caso tendría de que crear una función en view.py, crearle una url. Cómo le pasaría los parámetros desde javascript??

Comment: Haciendo una petición AJAX, esto se explica en la pregunta que enlace.

Comment: Estoy leyendo el enlace pero el toma los valores desde los input y yo solo quiero dar click en el botón y que se ejecute la función, no necesito que me de respuesta en otro input

Comment: Bueno pues entonces has una petición AJAX a secas osea sin enviar nada, y pues mandas a llamar la función, solo adapta la solución de la pregunta a tu problema.

Comment: Vale gracias intentare adaptar el la funcion para que llame solamente a la funcion

Comment: OK, pero creo que hay mejores soluciones, porque no directamente haces una petición AJAX al servicio web? En todo caso, suerte! :)

Comment: Sip, el echo es que tengo hecho la llamada al servicio web con javascript y funciona bien pero solo trabaja del lado cliente y necesito que sea del lado servidor

Comment: Mmmm entiendo, de igual manera suerte!.

Comment: Ya logre, que me funcione pero cuando inspecciono en algún momento da un error HTTP 500 que podría ser, aunque no impide que todo trabaje bien

Comment: No tengo ni la menor idea del porque sucede eso... Intuyo que algo haces mal...